# ASP .NET MVC4 Datepicker with month and year only

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to make a datepicker which will display years and month only.

I saw this questions in different places but all the solutions I have tested doesn't work.

I follow this example : http://jsfiddle.net/bopperben/DBpJe/

Here is my .cshtml file :

```
@using Site.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rapports";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
    });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>

<h2>Rapports</h2>

<div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
        <input type="submit" value="Rechercher" />
    } 

</div>
```

But in my page there is only a textbox and nothing pop up when I click it.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript error?

Comment: No, I don't have any error.

Comment: The code you copied was having syntax error. Can you please verify its correct?

Comment: Works fine in latest Chrome. Why dont you just create two <select> fields containing years and months? That will work with all browsers for sure.

Comment: have you referenced jQuery and jQueryUI ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you start from an ASP.NET MVC4 internet template?

I've tried your code above and got it working on two details.

I added the script tag in a section scripts (that will make sure it renders after jquery is loaded)

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

In the _Layout.cshtml I've added the jquerui bundle (script and style) (loads jqueryui in the page)

```
//In head tag
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

//After closing footer tag

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It works, the only thing missing was 
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` in the _Layout.cshtml

Thank you!

Comment: I have another question, do you know what file I have to modify to have years before this year only (so nothing after 2013)?

Comment: Problem solved, just have to add this line to my script : 
`yearRange: "-20:+0"`